# B2B Experience site - Get Current CartId

Tags: community, lightning-experience, commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce, b2b

I am developing LWC on a community site of b2b commerce. Is there a way to get the current cartId directly from the LWC or I have to get it from soql?

note: I cannot get it from {!recordId} because the component is not on the cart page.

Edit: Alternatively, which condition I need to add to the query to get the current cart ?

Comment: Hi Raphael! If the component is attached to Cart Page & Checkout Page you could leverage the {!recordId} to query the cart id. However in my experience, if not, you have to perform soql to retrieve it. You would need the following fields to get the correct cart

Webcart.OwnerId
Webcart.AccountId
Webcart.WebStoreId 
Webcart.Status = Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import `CartSummaryAdapter` from `commerce/cartApi` and wire that to retrieve the current active cart Id:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";

import { CartSummaryAdapter } from "commerce/cartApi";

export default class GetCartId extends LightningElement {
    @wire(CartSummaryAdapter)
    setCartSummary({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log("Cart Id", data.cartId);
        } else if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.242.0.b2b_b2c_comm_dev.meta/b2b_b2c_comm_dev/b2b_b2c_comm_display_lwc_apis.htm