# How to make patch request to /commerce/webstores/webstoreId/checkouts/activeOrCheckoutId from my custom LWC checkout component on the new LWR TEMPLATE

Tags: b2b-commerce, lwr, b2b

Most of the user interaction on the checkout page in the new LWR template for B2B Commerce are making get or patch callouts to /commerce/webstores/webstoreId/checkouts/activeOrCheckoutId to get data or update user input.
I did not find any examples in the documentation, and It does not explain how the default components work. I am doing custom chield LWC, and I wonder how best to do these callouts in my component.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the Callouts from Apex, or a better option would be to use the Wire Adapters and Imperative Methods that Salesforce have released:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.242.0.b2b_b2c_comm_dev.meta/b2b_b2c_comm_dev/b2b_b2c_comm_display_lwc_apis.htm

I left a comment [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/405024/7043), with info on how to get the current Active Carts info, I have been using a mix of this and DML Statements on the WebCart Object to make the necessary updates to custom fields, but then using the standard Checkout buttons so I don't need to actually make any API requests.